# Close related, but not grouped windows at once

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

When opening enough windows from one application, they become grouped and can be closed via `Right-Click` + `Close All`, as you can see on this screenshot

[image: Image1]

However, it seems to not be possible to close all windows from one application when they are not grouped in the taskbar:

[image: IMage2]

I am using Windows 10.

**Edit:** I am looking for a built-in functionality of Windows (such as shortcuts like `Alt + F4` or `Ctrl + W`) as it would be convenient to be able to use this regardless of the system one is working on.

**Hence my question:**

Is it possible to close multiple windows from the same application at once when they are not grouped?

Comment: *"close all similar windows when they are not grouped"* What do you mean by "similar"?

Comment: @Borodin I mean multiple windows which belong to _one_ application, e.g. multiple photos opened like in my screenshots

Comment: @EnzoVolkmann: So you want to work with a group of programs as if WIndows had gathered them together because there was a lack of space on the task bar? Do you want to do this from the GUI or from a program?

Comment: @Borodin Exactly. I want to do it from the GUI since it would be more convenient than closing the windows one by one.

Comment: Okay. I don't know a solution, and I think the answer is going to be that you can't do that because Windows isn't written that way. It might have been nice if MS had thought of allowing you to Ctrl-click to select a number of task bar items, but that certainly doesn't work. I can't see how it could be a big deal though. Do you spend a lot of your day closing multiple copies of the same program? Perhaps it's just that you're into skinning your Windows interface.

Comment: Fortunately this doesn't fill my day  It came to my mind while preparing a powerpoint presentation and downloading many icons from flaticon.com. I just copy-pasted them from the Photos app and ended up having many open windows of that kind.

Comment: You could create a desktop shortcut to a command line that does `taskkill /im program.exe` if it's something that happens a lot.

Comment: Would it be possible to link that to a Keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Yes, it would. But it must be the same program every time.